# Copying named ranges that contain a certain value to another worksheet with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a worksheet with 100 to 200 named ranges.  I would like to search each of the named ranges en when they contain a certain value in any of the cells in the range, the range should be copied to another worksheet.

I am new to VBA.  So any help is useful.  Always nice to learn a thing or two :)

Comment: I have never created anything like you are asking, but it seems that what you are asking will require a bit of coding and if you are new, it's going to be a bit more tricky. I found this [Link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-named-ranges-14513df5-0d79-4cd5-9a03-968905b244e6) on how you can manually search and find a named Range.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please verify [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and post what was tried.